# I forgot to mention that i did ghusl after doing ghusl

Tags: ghusl

Today I did ghusl to rid of janabat. I kept niyyah and did ghusl. However after I finished ghusl I forgot to declare that I have finished ghusl and say the dua after ghusl, as my mind was occupied with other thoughts. I remembered about it only a some time later.

So is my ghusl valid  ? Should I make ghusl again ? What about the prayers done in such a state?  If ghusl is invalid should it be redone (although I was ignorant of the matter ) ?

Comment: Why would that be even necessary? Who said so?

Answer (score 0):

Valid. What matters is the niyyah in the heart and the ghusl itself. I don't recall any hadith that said it's obligatory to declare the finish of ghusl or dua after ghusl (correct me if i'm wrong). And Allah knows best.